# Only destroy depdendents (aka: Is "send :_run_destroy_callbacks" code smell?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have implemented a safe destroy method for our User model since users can only be hard destroyed unless the user has surveys, otherwise, a soft destroy (by setting `deleted_at`) is done:

```
alias_method :original_destroy, :destroy

def destroy
  if surveys.any?
    update_column :deleted_at, DateTime.now
    surveys.each { |s| s.anonymize }
    send :_run_destroy_callbacks
    @destroyed = true
    freeze
  else
    original_destroy
  end
end
```

I'm not sure whether there's a better way to destroy all associationes with `dependent: destroy` than the `send :_run_destroy_callbacks` line above.

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this myself: For Rails 4 you should use `run_callbacks(:destroy) { ... }` instead.